# how to find the Speed of the Network connection in IOS apps

Tags: ios, swift2, reachability

I see a lot of threads and discussions on IOS Apps to determine if the device is connected to internet or not.. With this / is it possible to determine the speed of internet connection like differentiating if the connection is Very bad, bad, good and High Speed or anything similar to mobile networks like (E, H, H+, 3G & 4G). Looking forward to hear your comments.
Regards
Suresh

Answer (score 0):

**It could not answer your question at all** but you can use the same approach of speedtest.net and other speed tests:
You can create a file of 1MB for example and let the client download it so you can check how many seconds the client needs to download the file and from those seconds you can understand the speed.

(I am aware that it is not a a properly answer so before some downvotes let discuss in the comments)

Answer (score 0):

If you read the iOS documentation, you will find there are calls that tell you whether your device has a SIM card, and what kind of connectivity it has.